# Java, two objects, one cannot be resolved in methods, other can

Tags: java, object

Having an issue with two objects I've declared.  One is working fine, the p1, while the other, p2, cannot be resolved as a symbol of my methods.

The two objects are located in main, while the methods are located in a Player class.  I've tried moving variables and the objects around, but to no avail, as it causes other issues with scope.

Is this an issue with a scope?  But then why is one object seen in the methods and one isn't?  New to the whole object-oriented stuff as well, and it's throwing me for a loop.

The error is "cannot resolve symbol 'p2' "

The below code is the main method so far, then one of the methods that have the p2 error.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Player p1 = new Player(name1); // instantiation of player 1 object; given first player's name
    Player p2 = new Player(name2); // instantiation of player 2 object; given second player's name
}



    public void attack1(Player p1) { // first method in which player 2 attacks player 1
        Random rnd = new Random(); // instantiation of new random object
        int dmg = rnd.nextInt(26) - 1; // setting of variable dmg to = a random number between 0 and 25
        if (dmg >= 0 && dmg <= 15) { // if statement checking if dmg is between 0 and 15
            p1.health = p1.health - dmg; // if dmg is between 0 and 15, reduce value from player 1 health
            System.out.printf("%s attacked %s and %s's health is now %d.", p2.name, p1.name, p1.name, p1.health); // print to screen results of attack1
        } else if (dmg > 15) { // if dmg value is greater than 15, player 2 misses player 1
            System.out.printf("%s attacked %s and missed.", p2.name, p1.name); // print to screen results of missed attack1
        }
```

Comment: Yes, `attack1` method does not know anything about `p2` - maybe make `p1` and `p2` fields rather than local variables

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by making fields for them?  Sorry, I'm still incredibly novice.  Also, I have an attack2 class that takes in Player p2, and it has the same issue.  p1 works, p2 doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `p2` is not defined in the scope of the function `attack1`. Either pass both `p1` and `p2` to `attack1` or make `p1` and `p2` instance variables of your class.

```
public void attack1(Player p1, Player p2) { // first method in which player 2 attacks player 1
    Random rnd = new Random(); // instantiation of new random object
    int dmg = rnd.nextInt(26) - 1; // setting of variable dmg to = a random number between 0 and 25
    if (dmg >= 0 && dmg <= 15) { // if statement checking if dmg is between 0 and 15
        p1.health = p1.health - dmg; // if dmg is between 0 and 15, reduce value from player 1 health
        System.out.printf("%s attacked %s and %s's health is now %d.", p2.name, p1.name, p1.name, p1.health); // print to screen results of attack1
    } else if (dmg > 15) { // if dmg value is greater than 15, player 2 misses player 1
        System.out.printf("%s attacked %s and missed.", p2.name, p1.name); // print to screen results of missed attack1
    }
```

As a side note, I would suggest that you remove `attack1` and (presumably) `attack2` and instead write a method `public void attack(Player source, Player target)` to reduce the amount of duplicated code.

```
public void attack(Player source, Player target) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int damage = random.nextInt(26) - 1;
    if(damage >= 0 && damage <= 15) {
        target.health -= damage;
        System.out.printf("%s attacked %s and %s's health is now %d.", source.name, target.name, target.name, target.health);
    } else if(damage > 15) {
        System.out.printf("%s attacked %s and missed.", source.name, target.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you!  Thanks for the advice as well.